# unable to access peripheral settings using intent

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-intent

I am trying to open the settings page using intent for peripheral devices in tablet .

But i am finding no parameters in action_settings.

Please help me . your help will be much appreciated

Comment: I do not recall ever seeing a Settings screen with a "Peripheral devices" label. This might be specific to some device models. If so, Android itself will not have an `Intent` action in the SDK for it. If you are in position to do so, you might want to upload a screenshot of where this screen appears.

Comment: this is custom tablet idemia .. if you go to settings there is one option in devices called as peripheral power management which has option to enable/disble fingerprint option & cardreader slot

Answer (score 0):

That would appear to be a custom change to the Settings app made by that manufacturer. The manufacturer might be able to suggest an `Intent` that leads to that particular screen. However, you will not find a documented `Intent` action in the Android SDK for it, as it is not a standard Settings screen.

If you wanted to try an undocumented approach, you could check Logcat and see what entries are logged when you click the Settings item to open that screen. Activity starts get logged with some `Intent` details, and you may be able to reverse-engineer the `Intent` that your app can use that way.

Comment: i am getting this error now . can you please help ..---->     java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denial: writing to settings requires android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS

Comment: @angelina: You are trying to modify something that you cannot modify. Ordinary apps cannot hold `WRITE_SETTINGS` -- that is mostly for pre-installed apps and the firmware.